# Pcf8591 (AD/DA) module I2C, does it work with RPi?

Tags: analog-to-digital

Most of the RPi modules and equipments available online, are not available locally. This is the only ADC that is available locally to me. I'd like to know if it is compatible to use with Raspberry Pi Model B?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the make & model of this item? Otherwise we really can't help you very much, as there is no way to tell if it is the exact same one as someone has.

Comment: cant find a schematic for it anywhere on the web...typical of the raspberry pi subculture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. I have one at home and it works like a charm.